# How do you convert an entity's attribute of type int16 to string to be output to the user?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have tried different methods for converting a value of type integer 16 to a string but none work. When an entity returns a numerical value, is it of a different type than what it is?

```
NSString *stringToGoOut =[@[entity valueForKey:@"value1"] stringValue];

NSString *stringToGoOut2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [entity valueForKey:@"value2"]];
```

the second one shows an error saying that the formate specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'id_Nullable and request that i change the place holder from %i to %@ for string but when i do that, it outputs 0 overtime regardless of what has been entered on the previous screen

```
NSString *stringToGoOut2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[entity valueForKey:@"value2"]];
```

this worked sort of, but the output was a long number (i am guessing the location in memory) to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core data stores all the numbers as `NSNumber`.

So if you would like to print out the value this line should work

```
NSString *stringToGoOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entity.value1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`valueForKey:` returns an object so to convert to a string either

`NSString *stringToGoOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [entity valueForKey:@"value1"]];`

or

`NSString *stringToGoOut = [[entity valueForKey:@"value1"] stringValue];`

will work.

If it is outputting 0 then `[entity valueForKey:@"value1"]` is probably an NSNumber